# Integrating Python modules with the third party libraries for iOS Swift

Tags: python, ios, swift, pythonista

I have a use case where I need to integrate python algorithm(python 3.6). I'm able to run the simple scripts for MacOS and very simple Hello_world program on iOS using pythonista.

Is there any way to integrate more complex python modules with third party dependencies like numpy and scipy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Pyto-Python 3` is a great app which has modules with C extensions like `numpy`, `scipy` and `matplotlib` and more pre-installed (with a recent update you need to download them after downloading the app but it takes a minute or less) also it is open source, it has it’s own UI library which you can use it for making iOS and iPadOS apps with Pyto’s Xcode Template, also it is open source and the developer is easy to reach via GitHub and he really helps you with your problems, just open an issue at GitHub the developer answer in maximum one day, a also it has pip support so you can download packages easily, and lastly it has some special libraries like `music` and  `motion` which allows you to do things like access the data of magnometer, accelerometer and more!

Website: https://pyto.app/

Appstore Link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pyto-python-3/id1436650069?uo=4

Documentation link: https://pyto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/